# How do I run Kotlin libraries ( distributed via JitPack ) in a Java file?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jitpack

I have developed a library [Text2Summar](https://github.com/shubham0204/Text2Summary-Android)y for Android which is written using Kotlin. I am distributing this library using [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/docs/ANDROID/) and the building process goes perfectly fine.

Now, in a Kotlin-enabled Android project, I am able to import the classes available in the library. This is not the case in a project which only has Java ( no Kotlin configured ). Here, Android Studio simply complains that **cannot resolve symbol Text2Summary**.

> I have written the whole library in Kotlin and developers not using Kotlin are complaining about the same **cannot resolve symbol Text2Summary** error. Should I simply convert the Kotlin code back to Java code or should I tell the users to enable Kotlin by `apply plugin 'kotlin'`? A valid explanation will be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `@JvmStatic` annotation to make your method callable from Java code. Without it, you have to call it like `MyObject.Companion.method1()` in Java.

Here is what you should add to your public methods in `companion object {}`

```kotlin
class Text2Summary() {

    companion object {

        // Summarizes the given text.
        @JvmStatic
        fun summarize( text : String , compressionRate : Float ): String {
            val sentences = Tokenizer.paragraphToSentence( Tokenizer.removeLineBreaks( text ) )
            val tfidfSummarizer = TFIDFSummarizer()
            val p1 = tfidfSummarizer.compute( text , compressionRate )
            return buildString( sentences , p1 )
        }

        // Summarizes the given text. Note, this method should be used whe you're dealing with long texts.
        // It performs the summarization on the background thread. Once the process is complete the summary is
        // passed to the SummaryCallback.onSummaryProduced callback.
        @JvmStatic
        fun summarizeAsync( text : String , compressionRate : Float , callback : SummaryCallback ) {
            SummaryTask( text , compressionRate , callback ).execute()
        }
    }
}
```